# How to make jsonIgnore be able to setvalue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

Spring Boot 2.7.8

I have a simple POJO called participant. The front end sends an API request with the field IP which I want to store in the DB. However in the backend I am getting this field as null. The reason I have this field marked as jsonIgnore is because I don't want this field to be included in the get API response which works. I don't see this field in the response but in the initial API, the field is getting mapped as null as a result I am not able to store it.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name="participant")
public class Participant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long participantId; 
    private String ip;
    

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getIp(){return this.ip;}
    
}
```

REST Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addParticipant(@RequestBody Participant p) {
        .....

}
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>master</groupId>
    <artifactId>hype</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>hype</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    

</project>
```

The frontend API payload contains the field value

```
{
ip : "172.1.1.1"
}
```

but on the backend its null

```
{
ip: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@JsonIgnore is used at field level to mark a property or list of properties to be ignored. :)

With system design. You should't use an entity for request/response dto. for System security, You should provide a request/response dto, then map ( after bussiness logic) dto with entity then save data into DB. ( Adapter Design Pattern)

advantages of this way:

- You control dto( not entity).
- You can process data( validate, tranfom....)
- FE can only know the fields provided by BE
- When add/remove column in entity, FE don't need editing

Comment: Agree. Also, if GET payload is different from POST one, then you should have distinct DTOs for the two. Last, if the IP in the payload is the one of the device sending the request, you should read the IP from the request itself instead of trusting the client to provide it as part of the payload.